# Why is there only 1 type parameter in scala list flatmap parameter signature

Tags: scala

Why does `flatMap` for `List` takes only `B` as the type parameter

```
def flatMap[B](f: (A) => U[B]): U[B]
```

instead of

```
def flatMap[A, B](f: (A) => U[B]): U[B]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `A` is deduced from the type parameter defined on `List`:

```
sealed abstract class List[+A]
```

And since `flatMap` is defined for each element of type `A` in the `List`, there's no need to explicitly declare it.

Comment: Thanks, so does the compiler recognize this from the name of the type `A` eg. can I do this `def flatMap[B](f: (S) => U[B]): U[B`] or does it deduce from the actual type of the passed in function parameter?

Comment: It deduces it from the actual type of the `List`. i.e., if you had `List(1,2,3)`, `A` would be `Int`. You can easily see it when viewing the method inside an IDE.

Comment: The type parameter `A` is visible in the whole class `List` since it is defined at the level of the class. In the same way the type parameter `B` is visible in the whole method `flatMap` since that's where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is an object-oriented language. In object-oriented languages, methods always take an additional invisible (or not-so-invisible, e.g. in Python) argument, the so-called *receiver*, usually accessible inside the method using a pseudo-variable often called `this` or `self`. This receiver is special in the sense that it is privileged in two different areas:

- it takes part in dynamic ad-hoc polymorphism
- the method has access to its private implementation details

So, when looking at the parameter list of a method, you have to take this invisible parameter and its type into account.

In this case, the `flatMap` method is a member of the `List[+A]` class, so if we fold back that information into the signature, we get this:

```
def flatMap[A, B](me: List[A])(f: (A) => U[B]): U[B]
```

And as you can see, the type signature now matches with what you expect.